# Alien (1979) and Aliens (1986) watching order confusion between theatrical and director's cut

Tags: suggested-order, alien, aliens

I'm going to watch [Alien 1979](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0078748/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=2398042122&pf_rd_r=00G919W5QGFEHPXD34A4&pf_rd_s=top-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=m_chttp_tt_52) and [Aliens 1986](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0090605/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=2398042122&pf_rd_r=00G919W5QGFEHPXD34A4&pf_rd_s=top-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=m_chttp_tt_66), but I don't know which one to watch without missing out on the suspense and the actual charm of these movies. I'm confused on whether to watch theatrical cut or director's cut. I don't know which one to watch. Also it would be great if you can bring out the differences between the two.

**TLDR**; Which one should a beginner watch theatrical cut or director's cut for the movies [Alien 1979](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0078748/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=2398042122&pf_rd_r=00G919W5QGFEHPXD34A4&pf_rd_s=top-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=m_chttp_tt_52) and [Aliens 1986](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0090605/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=2398042122&pf_rd_r=00G919W5QGFEHPXD34A4&pf_rd_s=top-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=m_chttp_tt_66)?

Are the two movies [Alien 1979](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0078748/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=2398042122&pf_rd_r=00G919W5QGFEHPXD34A4&pf_rd_s=top-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=m_chttp_tt_52) and [Aliens 1986](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0090605/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=2398042122&pf_rd_r=00G919W5QGFEHPXD34A4&pf_rd_s=top-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=m_chttp_tt_66) interconnected? If yes, then are there any other movies in the same  series?

**Please note that I'm going to watch this movie for the first time.**

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you're asking.  Do you want to know whether to watch the theatrical cut or the director's cut on each movie?  The 1986 Alien is titled _Aliens_ and the 1979 one is just _Alien_.

Comment: Are you asking whether to watch Alien 1979 or Aliens 1986 first? Aliens 1986 is the sequel to Alien 1979 so I'd say watch the first one first.

Comment: @sanpaco I was asking whether to watch thretical cut or director's cut for both movies.

Comment: Watch them all ;)

Comment: @sanpaco Which one to watch first thretical cut or director's cut?

Comment: "are there any other movies in the same series?" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_(franchise)

Comment: I cannot answer, only comment. The Directors cut of Alien has some scenes which cause continuity problems (I won't go into detail), and therefor is slightly less suited as a part of the series. The Special Edition of Aliens on the other hand has none of these problems, and in my opinion has some nice extra scenes. I would watch the Theatrical cut of Alien, and the Special Edition of Aliens. In that order.

Answer (score 4):

Both are great, great films, you're gonna want to watch them multiple times so it really doesn't matter where you start.  Even watching them in reverse order doesn't matter, I saw Aliens first and it possibly made Alien even more intriguing.  You cannot go wrong - there are no bad versions.

However, assuming you do watch them more than once, start with the theatrical versions then there is more to discover when you watch the director's cuts.